# Subscribe to timeline updates - (400) callbackUrl must be a valid HTTPS URL

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I've been working with the [Mirror API](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/index), specifically the [php quick start](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php) project. I'm receiving an error after attempting to subscribe to timeline updates:

> An error occurred: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/subscriptions: (400) callbackUrl must be a valid HTTPS URL

I do have SSL enabled and working on my test server.

In the [subscribe_to_notifications](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/insert) function on mirror-client.php (line 111) I see a reference to the callbackUrl: `$subscription->setCallbackUrl($callback_url);`

However, I am not able to find where to change this. Should it be set to notify.php? Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue, in config.php my `$base_url` needed to be set to the secure version.